# Generating a map in android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

if i'm given a set of points(latitude,longitude) how can i generate a map with them between the points such that route generated is optimum.
i have no clue about it and so I've not mentioned the code along with it.

my purpose is to extract the latitudes and longitudes of points from a table in my local database and then generate a map with it .

Comment: what about creating a link to google maps? Google maps app can do your job if you need route task only.

Comment: i want to display the route from a source to a destination comprising of various points int between,i think google maps will only show the route from my source to destination.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Google Directions API to determine routes between each of the geolocations.  [Here is an introduction to Google Directions.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)  Part of the way down there is a, "Use Waypoints in Routes", which allow you to specify one or more addresses to determine a route.

If you need help getting started with Google Maps API, [here's an introduction.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is, can be acheived by google maps api, using waypoint parameter

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|via:Lexington,MA&key=API_KEY

in waypoint, either you can supply the location name or geo coordinates which should be delimeted by | incase you have multiple points, please follow this link for more detail about its usage.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests